# AngularJS Directive, link function has no context

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a custom AngularJS directive, and when I want to use DI from directive function ($parse service in this case), I cannot retrieve it:

[image]

This seems to me weird, because my code is here very similar to the provided documentation on custom directive:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
chapter "Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM" for example

Am i doing something wrong ??...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this `ReferenceError` because `$parse` is a closured variable from the parent scope ( it's parent function ), but it is not being used inside your `link` function, therefore it has been optimized away the moment you break there, and is no longer available for inspection.

If you assign `$parse` to a variable inside the `link` function you can inspect / use it. Try that and then see where you get stuck.

Comment: Well done, this was exactly the issue! $parse wasn't used and has been optimized. Thanks a lot